# waiting for long time when set save point in toad for sql server editor and executed from java?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, toad

I set the save point in toad for sql server like below

```
begin tran
clck1 save tran p1
delete from table_name where s_no>100;
```

Then i started running java program to take remaining data from `table_name` and to do process. But java waiting for long time and no moment. When I rolledback from editor by

```
rollback tran p1
```

then java program is running. Can anyone tell what is problem with java or save point.

Answer (score 0):

`BEGIN TRAN` is the start of a transaction.  It locks your table until you end your transaction.  This is why you're not able to access the table from your program.

You need to add `COMMIT` at the end of your `delete` statement to commit the change or `ROLLBACK` to - of course - roll it back.

Comment: thanks, this means i need to put like this begin tran clck1
save tran p1
delete from table where s_no>12000;
commit;
rollback tran p1

Comment: You should use one or the other after your delete statement.  COMMIT will _save_ your changes to the transaction log. ROLLBACK is to _undo_ your changes.